# how to buffer the latest value until another value arrive in another sequence by rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs5

I am trying to use rxjs in my project. I have following sequences, what I expected is that the 1rd sequence will only be handled after a value arrive in another sequence, and only the latest value in the 1st sequence will be reserved. Any suggestion for it?

```
s1$ |a---b----c-

s2$ |------o----
```

expected result:

```
s3$ |------b--c-
```

Comment: It looks like you want [`takeUntil()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) or [`skipUntil`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipUntil) but I don't think I understand your description. You can't get the expected `------|b-c-` because the complete signal is always the last one. In other words you can't emit more values after sending the complete signal.

Comment: @martin my description made some confusion, sorry for that. That | doesn't mean complete signal, I updated my description. I'm pretty new in rxjs. If I use takeUtil, I think I will lose b, and s1.subcribe will only fire after c arrive, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

I'd combine [`sample()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-sample) that is already very similar to what you need and [`skipUntil()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-sample).

```
const start = Scheduler.async.now();
const trigger = new Subject();

const source = Observable
    .timer(0, 1000)
    .share();

Observable.merge(source.sample(trigger).take(1), source.skipUntil(trigger))
    .subscribe(val => console.log(Scheduler.async.now() - start, val));

setTimeout(() => {
    trigger.next();
}, 2500);
```

This will output numbers starting with `2`.

```
source  0-----1-----2-----3-----4
trigger ---------------X---------
output  ---------------2--3-----4
```

Console output with timestamps:

```
2535 2
3021 3
4024 4
5028 5
```

Alternatively you could use `switchMap()` and `ReplaySubject` but it's probably not as obvious as the previous example and you need two Subjects.

```
const start = Scheduler.async.now();
const trigger = new Subject();

const source = Observable
    .timer(0, 1000)
    .share();

const replayedSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
source.subscribe(replayedSubject);

trigger
    .switchMap(() => replayedSubject)
    .subscribe(val => console.log(Scheduler.async.now() - start, val));

setTimeout(() => {
    trigger.next();
}, 2500);
```

The output is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I would do this using a `ReplaySubject`:

```js
const subject$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)

const one$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000) 
const two$ = Rx.Observable.interval(2500)

one$.subscribe(subject$)

const three$ = two$
  .take(1)
  .flatMap(() => subject$)

// one$   |----0---1---2---3---4---
// two$   |----------0---------1---
// three$ |----------1-2---3---4---
```

Answer (score -1):

last + takeUntil will work

here is an example:

```
let one$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
let two$ = Rx.Observable.timer(5000, 1000).mapTo('stop');

one$
  .takeUntil(two$)
  .last()
  .subscribe(
     x=>console.log(x),
     err =>console.error(err),
     ()=>console.log('done')
  );
```

Comment: Your stream ends and does not take the newest values.